# CSS3 - Multiple backgrounds sometimes causes 404 errors

Tags: css, http-status-code-404, background-image

I'm using the CSS3 ability to apply multiple background images to an element. Currently, I have this code in my stylesheet:

```
body{background:url("images/emblem.png") top center no-repeat, url("images/background.png");background-color:#EAE6D9}
```

The code works in all browsers that support it. And those that it doesn't defaults down to the `background-color`.

However, watching the access log files for the site, I'm noticing 404 errors pop up for, what looks to be, a malformed request based on this CSS initiative. The funny thing is, they are coming from someone using Firefox 5. I'm using Firefox 5 and I cannot get an error to show up in the log for my IP.

Here's the error line from the log:

```
10.21.7.246 - - [28/Jun/2011:12:02:01 -0500] "GET /templates/images/emblem.png%22),%20url(%22http://ulabs.illinoisstate.edu/templates/images/background.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1005 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
```

I have a feeling the problem is coming from the fact that the `"` and the space is being URL encoded, but I'm definitely not doing that. And it doesn't happen all the time. Looking at requests from my IP address, the request is properly split up.

```
10.1.8.129 - - [28/Jun/2011:12:29:33 -0500] "GET /templates/images/background.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://ulabs.illinoisstate.edu/templates/style.1308848695.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
10.1.8.129 - - [28/Jun/2011:12:29:33 -0500] "GET /templates/images/emblem.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://ulabs.illinoisstate.edu/templates/style.1308848695.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
```

Has anyone experienced this behavior before? Or have any ideas on what I might try to resolve the issue?

Comment: I agree it's probably the `"`, but it's weird that it's not consistent. Is there a reason you want to leave the quotes in? It's still valid CSS without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've discovered it's YSlow causing the error to be generated. When running YSlow, the error would appear in the log immediately for that IP address. Since this really isn't really a problem, luckily there's nothing we need to fix on our end.